# Where does Selenium store the DOM, if at all?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to understand the performance impacts of things like `WebDriver.findBy(...)`. For example if I was using Selenium to drive a local Chrome instance:

```
WebElement betty = webDriver.findBy(By.id("betty"));
```

Does the Selenium library

a) have the DOM within the JVM to evaluate?

b) go to the local Chrome driver binary to evaluate?

c) go to the browser instance to evaluate?

And does the answer change for a [Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/grid/) situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a nice [technical guide](https://seleniumjava.com/2015/09/13/how-does-selenium-webdriver-work/) that explains this.

> The browser driver uses an `HTTP SERVER` which **waits continuously for
> new Selenium commands**.
>
> It has the following purposes:
>
> - read HTTP requests coming from the client (client = computer that executes the test automation scripts)
> - determines the series of steps needed for implementing the Selenium command
> - sends the implementation steps to the browser
> - gets the execution status from the browser
> - send the execution status back to the client
>
> **For each Selenium command of the automation script, a http request with a specific path is created**.
>
> When the automation script is executed, the first http request generates a new session that is specific to the browser where the automation scripts run.
>
> The session id will be used for the http requests that correspond to all other
> Selenium commands from the automation script.

Comment: Great find, thanks. So in summary, no caching, we are going over the network (albeit locally or remotely) via the driver to the browser for those kind of operations.

Comment: @markdsievers Yes. If the DOM was cached implicit and explicit waits would have lost all meaning.